# JavascriptでiBeaconを検知したい（バックグラウンド）

Tags: ios, monaca, ibeacon

HTML5,CSS,Javascript (Monava) でバックグラウンドでアプリを起動していなくてもiBeaconを検知できるようにしたいです。
機種は iOS8,3 です。
Objective-C ではできるようですが
http://www.gaprot.jp/pickup/ibeacon/ibeacon-vol2/
Monacaを使ってはできないのでしょうか？
ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

できますよ。バッググラウンドだけでなく、Killしても検知します。(rangingでなくmonitoringのみ)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940742/cordova-ibeacon-send-local-notification-after-the-app-got-killed-but-does-not
この辺りが参考になるかと思います！